# Pickle losing one one of my arguments

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, pickle

I'm having trouble with pickle: I have a tricky use case and I'm not getting back a duplicate of the object I pickled. If I start with

```
class OneArg(object):
    def __init__(self, somearg, *args, **kwargs):
        print "In OneArgs's init with args={} and kwargs={}".format(args, kwargs)
        self._somearg = somearg
        super(OneArg, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class OneArgSubclass(OneArg, OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "In OneArgSubclass's init with args={} and kwargs={}".format(args, kwargs)
        super(OneArgSubclass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


def verbose_pickle_dumps (obj):
    result = pickle.dumps(obj)
    print result
    return result


oas = OneArgSubclass("SOMEARG")
oas['spam'] = 'eggs'
oas_red = pickle.loads(verbose_pickle_dumps(oas))
print "oas_red.keys():", oas_red.keys()
```

Here's the output I get:

```
In OneArgSubclass's init with args=('SOMEARG',) and kwargs={}
In OneArgs's init with args=() and kwargs={}
oas.keys(): ['spam']

c__main__
OneArgSubclass
p0
((lp1
(lp2
S'spam'
p3
aS'eggs'
p4
aatp5
Rp6
(dp7
S'_somearg'
p8
S'SOMEARG'
p9
sb. 

In OneArgSubclass's init with args=([['spam', 'eggs']],) and kwargs={}
In OneArgs's init with args=() and kwargs={}
oas_red.keys(): []
```

I can see that when I pickle oas, the 'spam'/'eggs' key/value pair is in there, and so is the value of _somearg. Note that the string "OrderedDict" does not appear,however. When I try to load oas back from pickle, it doesn't pick up the string 'SOMEARG' and so the contents of the dictionary end up in as the value of _somearg instead.

I've looked and oas has neither __getinitargs__() nor __getnewargs__(). If I use a regular dict instead of an OrderedDict the code works (and the pickled representation looks quite pretty different, including mentioning 'copy_reg'), so I thought that the issue might be compatibility between pickle and OrderedDict. But pickle works fine when I work with an OrderedDict by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pickle something there are [several different methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#the-pickle-protocol) that can be used to extract the data to recreate the object on unpickling.  The problem you are running in to is that `OrderedDict` defines one of them (`__reduce__`), but what it returns is not compatible with your `__init__` -- so you'll need to write your own:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    return (self.__class__, (self._somearg, tuple(self.items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to implement a `__repr__()` method for your class, as here: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/781057-pickle-instance-custom-class.

In their example, they derive a class from `OrderedDict`, and implement a `__repr__()` method this way

```
def __repr__(self):
        return '{%s}' % ', '.join([': '.join([repr(k),str(v)]) \
                                   for k,v in zip(self.keys(), self.values())])
```

when the class `__init()__` stands

```
class OrderedDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, d = None):
        self._keys = []
        if d == None: d = {}
        self.update(d)
```